# Can you set a specific X, Y position for CTLegend

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, legend

I am using the apache POI and the OpenOffice libraries to create bar and line charts.  I can get the combination bar and line chart to work fine, and to create a nice legend.  But I'd like to position it using something besides the enum values from STLegendPos (.L, .B, .R, .T, .TR).  The spreadsheet I'm generating has a lot of sheets with charts and the legend is covering up the Y axis.  I'm setting the addNewOverlay() to true, because I need it on top of the chart, but I just want to move it programatically over to the right a little without having the user needing to go in and move about 70 legends.

My code for adding a chart legend is as follows:

```
private static void addChartLegend(CTChart ctChart) {
    // Define legends for the chart and set the position of the legend
    CTLegend    ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
    ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.L);

    // Set border color
    ctLegend.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0});

    // Set fill color
    ctLegend.getSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255});
    ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(true);  // true overlays it on top of chart; false creates it's own space
}
```

I've searched a lot trying to find an example of setting the exact position with no luck.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.
Geoff

Comment: [CTLegend.addNewLayout()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTLegend.java#CTLegend.addNewLayout()) -> [CTLayout.addNewManualLayout()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTLayout.java#CTLayout.addNewManualLayout()) -> [CTManualLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTManualLayout.java) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `CTLegend` already, then you can apply a `CTLayout` using [CTLegend.addNewLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTLegend.java#CTLegend.addNewLayout()). Then a `CTManualLayout` must be applied using [CTLayout.addNewManualLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTLayout.java#CTLayout.addNewManualLayout()). Then in the [CTManualLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTManualLayout.java), the `CTLayoutMode`s `XMode` and `YMode` must be set and then the double values `X` and `Y`.

The main problem is getting information what is the meaning of the `XMode` and `YMode` and `X`and `Y`. For this see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff534056(v=office.12).aspx:

"For **xMode / yMode** element, the **edge** attribute specifies that the value of sibling element **x / y**  is interpreted as the distance to the left/top edge of the chart element from the left/top edge of the chart as a **percentage** of the chart width/height."

Code example:

```
    //legend
    CTLegend ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
    ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.L);
    ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);
    CTManualLayout ctManualLayout = ctLegend.addNewLayout().addNewManualLayout();
    ctManualLayout.addNewXMode().setVal(STLayoutMode.EDGE);
    ctManualLayout.addNewYMode().setVal(STLayoutMode.EDGE);
    ctManualLayout.addNewX().setVal(0.00); //left edge of the chart
    ctManualLayout.addNewY().setVal(0.25); //25% of chart's height from top edge of the chart
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.  I could see some of these methods, but was having a hard time finding documentation or examples that would give me enough help.  The only thing I needed to change was I set addNewOverlay() to true because I don't want it out to the side, and I set the addNewX() value to 0.10 to move it slightly to the right of the Y axis.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @G.Price: You are welcome. And yes the Office Open XML is open documented but nevertheless this documentation is cryptically in many parts. And yes it is hard to follow the idea to set a top/left position of an element as a distance from the top/left edge in **percent** of the height/width of the containing element. The one who had this idea must have worked too long this day ;-).